# How to assign GUID to records in Firebase Realtime Database when importing JSON

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to import a large dataset into a Firebase Realtime Database for a new Android app. Preparing the data is not a problem, I have a VBA script in Excel that does this, however, I would like to have some nodes in the imported database to have a GUID, like the ones generated when "pushing" new data to Firebase. I am not able to find out how to do this.

For example if I import this test dataset:

```
{
"Genera": {
    "Genus_1": {
        "S001" : {
            "name": "name_1",
            "common_name": "common_1"
        },
        "S002": {
            "name": "name_2",
            "common_name": "common_2"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the "Genus_1" and "Sxxxx" strings with a GUID-type string.

If this is possible how would I achieve it.
Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us how your changed schema should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a single JSON snippet into the Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase does not generate any keys for child data for you. This means you have two options:

1. Import each part in an individual call.
2. Pre-generate your own keys.

#### Import each part in an individual call

If you want Firebase to generate a key for specific parts of your JSON, you will need to call the Firebase API for each such part, calling `push()` or its equivalent for the platform you use. E.g.

```
curl -X POST -d '{
  "S001" : {
    "name": "name_1",
    "common_name": "common_1"
  }
}' 'https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/Genera.json'
```

Since you're using `POST` here, the Firebase server will generate a new key under `Genera` for the JSON in this call.

#### Pre-generate your own keys

If you want to import the JSON in one go, you will have to pre-generate the keys yourself. Luckily the [algorithm for generating push IDs is available online](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11), and documented in this blog post: [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt answer Frank. Since my JSON is being generated in Excel I will need to port the algorithm to VBA, should be possible.